# I cannot view the data as I am processing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oop

I filter the titles I want with the filter function. Then I want to view the data with show_data operation. However, the data comes in its original form. does not come filtered. how can I do that?
Very very very thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import os


class MainData:
    csv_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/dataset/traffic-crashes- 
    vehicles-1.csv")
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_path)

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = data


    def filter(self):
        self.data = self.data[['MAKE','NUM_PASSENGERS']]
        return self.data


    def show_data(self):
        a = self.data
        return self.data

    MainData().filter()
    MainData().show_data()
```

Comment: did you call `filter` method before `show_data` ?

Comment: I run it that way, but unfortunately when I return self.data, the first data comes again.

Comment: create object first then use `instance method`

Comment: This should be raising an error. That's not how you call those methods. It should at least be something like `MainData().filter()`. *After* the class definition, not within it.

Comment: `self.data =...` creates a new instance-bound attribute "data" but doesn't modify the original class-bound "data". Then you throw away the instance with its attribute and create a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for their help. I've made progress. I will now look at the next problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an object for the class. Then use that object to call methods of the class:

```
obj = MainData()
obj.filter()
obj.show_data()
```